# Parse a JSON array with multiple object types

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have a JSON array like this:

```
"videos": [
      {
        "id": 25182,
        "game": 115653,
        "name": "Trailer",
        "video_id": "BdA22Lh6Rwk"
      },
      27749,
      {
        "id": 29188,
        "game": 115653,
        "name": "A New Team and New Rivals in Pokémon Sword and Pokémon Shield! ⚔️️",
        "video_id": "ZBiTpi8ecTE"
      }
    ]
```

Normally if the item's JSON format in `videos` is like `videos[0]` or `videos[2]` then I was able to parse it to `Video` like this:

```
json['videos']?.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()?.map<Video>((f) {
        return Video.fromJson(f);
    })?.toList();
```

My `Video` class:

```
class Video {
  int id;
  int game;
  String name;
  String videoId;

  Video({this.id, this.game, this.name, this.videoId});

  Video.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    game = json['game'];
    name = json['name'];
    videoId = json['video_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['game'] = this.game;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['video_id'] = this.videoId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

But if something with the different structure like `videos[1]` is within the array then I ended up with `Exception`. How can I parse `videos[1]` to `Video` with `video[1]` as `Video`'s `id`?

Comment: Do you mean `videos[1]` in your last line? It is not recommended to use the JSON format you are having. You should have "homogeneous" children of the array.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh Yes, i mean `videos[1]`, my bad. I know it is not a recommended way to use a JSON format like that but unfortunately changing response's JSON format is not something under my control :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the different formats and figure out which one each entry is.
You can do that by checking the type of the entry: Is it an integer or a map?

Example:

```
List<Video> videosFromJson(List<Object> videoJson) {
  var result = <Video>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < videoJson.length; i++) {
    var entry = videoJson[i];
    if (entry is Map<String, dynamic>) {
      result.add(Video.fromJson(entry));
    } else if (entry is int) {
      result.add(Video()..id = entry);
    } else {
      throw FormatException("Not a recognized video format", entry, i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for easy to understand explanation.